# Why does CanvasRenderingContext2D.putImageData’s performance degrade through repetitive invocations?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

When calling a canvas’ 2D rendering context’s `putImageData` method repeatedly, its performance degrades quite quickly and very noticably in Chromium.

Use the following code to reproduce this behaviour:

```
const source = document.getElementById('source')
const dest = document.getElementById('dest')
const output = document.getElementById('output')

// Get the drawing contexts from both canvases,
// and cache the source canvas’ image data
const sourceCtx = source.getContext('2d')
const destCtx = dest.getContext('2d')
const imgData = sourceCtx.getImageData(0, 0, 50, 50)

const outerIterations = 50
const innerIterations = 1e3
// Repeatedly copy the source canvas’ image data to the dest’s.
for (let i=0; i<outerIterations; i++) {
  
  // This loop is just to increase the number of draws
  // without printing the performance measure that often
  for (let j=0; j<innerIterations; j++) {
    destCtx.putImageData(imgData, 0, 0)
  }

  // Only every once in a while, check the performance
  const start = performance.now()
  destCtx.putImageData(imgData, 0, 0)
  const end = performance.now()
  console.log(`Iteration ${(i+1) * innerIterations + 1} took ${end - start}ms\n`)

  //  Iteration  Elapsed time
  //       1001  0.12
  //       5001  0.74
  //      10001  2.09
  //      15001  3.94
  //      20001  5.52
}
    <canvas id="source" width="50" height="50"></canvas>
    <canvas id="dest" width="75" height="75"></canvas>
```

Firefox does not immediately exhibit this behaviour. However, if the code is changed such that the source context’s image data changes between the calls to `putImageData`, Firefox’s performance degrades, too, as is shown by the following snippet:

```
const source = document.getElementById('source')
const dest = document.getElementById('dest')

// Get the drawing contexts
const sourceCtx = source.getContext('2d')
const destCtx = dest.getContext('2d')
drawCircle()
function drawCircle() {
  sourceCtx.ellipse(25, 25, 25, 25, 0, 0, 7);
  sourceCtx.fill();
  sourceCtx.stroke();
}

function copyCircle() {
  drawCircle();
  destCtx.putImageData(sourceCtx.getImageData(0, 0, 50, 50), 0, 0);
}

const outerIterations = 20;
const innerIterations = 5e2
// Repeatedly copy the source canvas’ image data to the dest’s.
for (let i=0; i<outerIterations; i++) {
  
  // This loop is just to increase the number of draws
  // without printing the performance measure that often
  for (let j=0; j<innerIterations; j++) {
    copyCircle();
  }

  // Only every once in a while, check the performance
  const start = performance.now();
  copyCircle();
  const end = performance.now();
  console.log(`Iteration ${(i+1) * innerIterations + 1} took ${end - start}ms\n`)
}
    <canvas id="source" width="50" height="50"></canvas>
    <canvas id="dest" width="75" height="75"></canvas>
```

Comment: A. `performance.now()` is milli (ms) not micro (μs) seconds B. Memory management is complex. Access to rendered pixels is already slow as pixels are in GPU memory not CPU. Memory you allocate needs to be de-allocated, this is done by the garbage collector (GC) and it's job is far from easy. The more you allocate the harder its job gets. There is also the memory used by the JS engine, Moving pixel to and from the GPU is not free and requires another level of device and memory management. Though I am unsure as to how chrome handles the heap, memory fragmentation will also effect performance

Comment: @Blindman67 (A) Corrected; thanks. (B) I can’t quite follow your reasoning. I am aware that data needs to be transferred to and from the CPU, but the amount of data doesn’t change though the iterations, so it should be equally fast each time – or at least only have an impact every once in a while when the GC runs. The canvases are tiny, so memory *may* be deallocated, but it should not be mandatory after each iteration. Lastly, the memory should aleady be allocated and only needs to be overwritten, if I’m not mistaken.

Comment: Each allocation gets s reference. GC watches the refs and removes memory associated when it can not find it in your code (For each ref GC must check every var & prop, in every scope, closure, & object) For best performance most of the time GC is held back unfortunately some times you get behavior as you observe . Under the hood reusing allocated mem would be a nightmare, & JS unusable. GPU/CPU interface is fussy about where when and how memory is moved making img data particularly complex..Less about # bytes more about the # refs. Try 50by100px per imgData, 2 * the RAM will not half the time